# Why does a fixed IR scanner sometimes measure my body temperature as ridiculously low consistently?

Tags: temperature

We have a fixed IR hand temperature scanner at work and sometimes on one day measures my body temperature as 24 degrees Celsius and it does several times in the same day. I have read on Thermos that they don't measure internal temperature, are sensitive to distance (it has a fixed distance) and have an error of +/-3 degrees. The first time of measurement as I just came in from a riding bicycle. All that shouldn't produce such a ridiculously temperature that I should be dead. At the same time, it produce reasonable reading for other people. Why would it produce low reading just for me?

Comment: Do you wear sunscreen on your hands? What if you point ot at something other than your hands? Or another IR thermometer?

Comment: What does "hand temperature scanner" mean? Are you talking about a device that you hold in your hand and point at your forehead? or are you talking about a device that looks at your hands? A device that looks at your forehead works, sorta, kinda, so long as you've been indoors in a normal residential/office temperature environment for the last half hour or so, and you've been wearing "normal" clothing (especially, no hat!). But, I can't imagine the temperature of your hands being a good indicator of your core temperature even under those circumstances.

Comment: I said fixed. It has a stand. You put your hands under it. It also has a preset alcohol spray. External temperatures are mild. No sunscreen on hands (specifically applied). No one holds the IR scanner. It detects your hands and then scans.

Answer (score 0):

> [Sometimes,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_thermometer) especially near ambient temperatures, readings may be subject to error due to the reflection of *radiation from a hotter body*—even the person holding the instrument[citation needed] — rather than radiated by the object being measured, and to an *incorrectly assumed emissivity.*

Italics mine.

Clothing can be either very hot, coming in from the sun, or much colder than the body. Is your temperature too much off when you have been in the office for some time?

Otherwise your [emissivity](https://www.npl.co.uk/resources/q-a/why-is-emissivity-important) must be different than average assumed in the thermometer, possibly again due to clothing, an aluminum weave jacket would block infrared from the body, for example.

Comment: Yes I am wondering if their skin was wet from perspiration and therefore reflective or caused other reading errors. @user2617804 you said you were cycling is it possible you were sweaty?